# Writing a recursive function with theano.scan

Tags: python, recursion, theano

I have the following function written in pure python

```
theta = 0.1
x_new = np.zeros_like(x)
x_new[0] = x[0]
                               
for index in range(1, len(x)):
  x_new[index] = x[index] + theta * x_new[index - 1]
```

I am trying to rewrite it with theano.scan but have difficulties defining the input for two arrays x_new and x

Hope experts in Theano can help.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Comment: Hi there.  What have you tried?  Please post some example code and the errors you got.  We aren't going to do all the work for you.

Comment: Hi @GaretJax I don't get it. I didn't ask an abstract or vague question that has multiple interpretations. My question should be simple for those who know theano and have experience with the scan function. I think the description of the problem and the inputs are clearly explained.

Comment: @slavakx - remember this is just my opinion.  I agree with what you said, but it appears from the question that you just threw it over the wall without trying to solve it yourself.  The fact that your question is 9 days old without even one answer seems to agree with me.